# Debian 10: Move System-Disk from SATA to USB

Tags: debian, usb-storage

I've a self build NAS-System which is running fine on Debian 10. It's  a RAID5 over 4 Disks and an SSD for the OS.

I would like to extend my RAID with 2 more Disk, but the MoBo only has 6 SATA. So my Idea is to just pull the SSD and plug it into an USB3-Port with an external HDD-Case.

So my Question is: Will it boot? Or what to do to make it boot?

Thanks for your help!

KR
Thorsten

Comment: You want to boot an SSD over USB?

Comment: I don't have enough SATA-Ports. Currently there are 4 RAID Disk and 1 SSD for the OS. I have to extend the RAID with 2 more Disk. So all SATA-Ports needed for RAID. 

I would like to pull the OS-SSD out of the SATA-Port, plug it in an USB-Case und boot the OS from USB.

Question is: Will Debian boot, or do i have to change somthing in GRUB or Elsewhere

Comment: This will likely boot and work, but very very slowly. I would more recommend one more SATA card, if there is place.

Comment: It booted, and it isn't slow. But most of the Discactivity is on the RAID.

Thank you!!